# Python regular expression to pull text inside of HTML quotation marks

Tags: python, regex, quotes

I'm attempting to pull ticker symbols from corporations' 10-K filings on EDGAR. The ticker symbol typically appears between a pair of HTML quotation marks, e.g., "&#145;" or "&#146;". An example of a typical portion of relevant text:

> Our common stock has been listed on the New York Stock Exchange (&#8220;NYSE&#8221;) under the symbol &#8220;RXN&#8221;

At this point I am just trying to figure out how to deal with the occurrence of one or more of a variety of quotation marks. I can write a regex that matches one particular type of quotation mark:

```
re.findall(r'under[^<]*the[^<]*symbol[^<]*&ldquo;*[^<]*\n',fileText)
```

However, I can't write a regex that looks for more than one type of quotation mark. This regex produces nothing:

```
re.findall(r'under[^<]*the[^<]*symbol[^<]*&ldquo;*&#145;*&#146;*&#147;*[^<]*\n',fileText)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a html parser

Comment: `(["'])((?:(?=(?:(\\))*)\3.|&#\d{3};)*?)\1`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you elaborate on why that would be preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks for **all** of the quotes occurring together. If you're looking for any **one** of the possibilities, you need to put parentheses around each string and `or` them:

```
(?:&ldquo;)*|(?:&#145;)*|(?:&#146;)*|(?:&#147;)*
```

The `?:` makes the paren groups non-capturing. I.e., the parser won't save each one as important text. As an aside, you'll probably want to use group-capturing to save the ticker symbol -- what you're actually looking for. **Very** quick-and-dirty (and ugly) expression that will return `['NYSE', 'RXN']` from the given string:

```
re.findall(r'(?:(?:&ldquo;)|(?:&#14[567];)|(?:&#822[01];))(.+?)(?:(?:&ldquo;)|(?:&#14[567];)|(?:&#822[01];))', fileText)
```

You'd probably want to only include left-quotes in the first group and right-quotes in the last group. Plus either-or quotes in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
re.sub("&#([0-9]+);", lambda x:chr(int(x.group(1))), text)
```

this works because you can use search/replace providing a callable for the replace part. The number after "#" is the unicode point for the character and Python `chr` function can convert it to text.

For example:

```
re.sub("&#([0-9]+);", lambda x:chr(int(x.group(1))),
       "this is a &#8220;test&#8220;")
```

results in

```
'this is a “test“'
```